# Discovering Hazelcast Cluster Groups

Tags: hazelcast

I'm using a couple of Hazelcast clusters for separate purposes and don't want them to interact so have used different cluster groups. I've written a simple monitor application to keep track of the members of each cluster, but wondered if there's a way of determining which cluster groups are reachable? The monitor connects as a client and I've had to hard code cluster group names in my application configuration so it can attempt to create a connection with each. That's fine for the moment with only two groups but as my usage expands it would be helpful if I could programmatically determine all the clusters available for connection - is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Group names are the credentials for the Clusters. Unless you know the name, you won't be able to connect to it.
We have a similar use-case and are handling this by maintaining a property of list of group names and just looping through them to check the connections. This requires you to either have a common group password or retrieve the corresponding passwords from other source.

Comment: Thanks - I though this was probably the case

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution: 
Instantiate two clients with different configs, one is configured for cluster1 and the other for cluster2. Attach, client lifecycle listener to each client. Look for CLIENT_DISCONNECTED and CLIENT_CONNECTED events.

Comment: Thanks but that still requires you to know in your app what all the possible group names are - I was hoping to be able to retrieve from Hazelcast a list of all locatable groups

Comment: There is no such an API to get a list of all the clusters at the environment. But this is a config that you have to setup for each cluster anyway. If you have access to the config xmls, you can parse all the xmls to get a list of group names. By the way, group name is a part of a security config.

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast members [exposes monitoring data via JMX](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Management/Monitoring_with_JMX.html) protocol. groupName and list of members can be discovered via JMX connection to a member:

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Management/JMX_API_Per_Member.html